# Should we set up some meta Wiki questions on determining well-written answers?

Tags: discussion, answers

[How do I know what the correct answer is?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84/how-do-i-know-what-the-correct-answer-is)

This question made me wonder whether lay-people and people like myself who are less-versed in legal research would benefit from a guide to legal research? And/or perhaps a list of legal resources? Other sites (such as ELL) have similar lists of off-site resources.

This would also be useful if we get simple, general reference questions such as simple case facts, or statute questions that don't require statutory interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Research questions in Main](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130/research-questions-in-main)

> Assuming these questions are within the scope of the site, they belong in the main Q&A. They do not belong in on the meta support site.

As per the answer here, posting guides to *reading* answers - case and statute citations, and so on **belong in Main**.

However, determining whether an answer is well-written - whether it is because of some unfounded assumption or assertion of the facts, or because of the wording - seems like it would belong in meta.

I'm going to leave this as the accepted answer because it should be more prominent (the answer to my *other* question has come from SE) but please feel free to continue to express views on this here, if you like.

Answer (score 3):

I agree this would be useful. In addition, it can be difficult to realize that an unfounded inference has been made in an answer. It takes critical thinking *and* experience in the field to recognise a slight difference in fact patterns that would distinguish the facts in a question from the facts in the case law being referenced in an answer. I think it would also be useful to develop a guide to critiquing legal arguments.