# Research questions in Main

Tags: discussion

I have continued the work that Christian Conkle started and done an Australian law case lookup question.

Before this runs away, are we comfortable with having these in main as opposed to Meta? I assume people will eventually exhaust the canonical research topics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming these questions are within the scope of the site, they belong in the main Q&A. They do not belong in on the meta support site.

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to confirm. I know that ELL maintains a list of resources on meta, but that'd be because it's off-topic for main.