# Answers without references

Tags: discussion, references, answers

*I've been thinking about this for a while - this is me without my moderator hat on, and no claim is made as to whether the other mods agree with or support these views.*

There are a *large number* of answers without references. Like, a lot of them. And where the question hasn't already cited a case or statute that it's asking about, it may certainly be a problem.

Why?

Because, there's no way for the person asking the question to validate or verify the response you give. And when we're providing information on the law, this is pretty important.

In most legal systems, only judges and legislators get to make up new law. This means that what we're saying, most of the time, is going to be an interpretation or quotation of something someone else has said in the past.

This issue has been discussed before: [Do answers need to reference written laws or court cases?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18/do-answers-need-to-reference-written-laws-or-court-cases)

The highest voted answer ([at the moment](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/23/1)):

> An answer will always be improved by a citation, but I don't think they should be mandatory. In many jurisdictions access to judgments is not free, so it would be a high bar to entry if we demanded that every answer cite correctly.
>
> People can always come along later and add missing citations to answers if that would improve them.

While this is true, it's probably best not to get in the habit of writing answers based on common sense. To [quote myself:](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22731487#22731487)

> The main problem is that people tend to agree with commonsensical answers, even if they're not legally sound :/

So in summary, my opinion:

- Unless you're answering a question *about* a case or statute, your answer is almost<sup>1</sup> always better with some kind of reference - and it's better for the person asking the question, too.
- Please, please don't answer with something that just *seems* right (I hope we don't have anyone doing this anyway, but included it for the avoidance of doubt)

#### Thoughts? Additions? Disagreements?

---

<sub>1. I mean, the reference obviously needs to be suitable for the answer - and the more specific the better</sub>

Answer (score 7):

All of my answers on Law Stack Exchange contain references. I'm not trying to tout that; it's simply because I'm used to it, coming primarily from Stack Exchange sites that either require or strongly encourage references. But it's vital for me to have references in my answers, because **I'm not a lawyer**. I have never been to law school (or college, yet). I have never been in a courtroom. I don't even know any lawyers. I barely even like courtroom dramas.

Stack Exchange sites are designed so that questions can be answered by experts. Everyone's proud of that. Every question deserves to have an expert answer. So why do I answer questions on Law, given that I'm not an expert? It's because I can cite experts. I know how to do research. When I answer, I quote prior decisions and the words of legal experts on the issue at hand. When possible, my answers come from experts - piecemeal, admittedly, but based on expert ideas.

[Many of us lament that fact that there are not many lawyers on Law.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10/2-what-should-our-documentation-contain/77#77) It is the great tragedy so far for the site. Fixable? Yes. But we need answers from legal experts to make the site as good as it can be. So what can we do, given that most of us are not lawyers? We can cite lawyers and legal experts.

My rationale for giving references for any and all claims is that every question deserves an expert answer. Not all of us can claim to be experts, but we can research and find what experts say on the issue. Then we can say that the question has gotten answers it deserves.

If we do this, Law Stack Exchange can be a great success.

Answer (score 5):

I pretty much agree, but as a serial offender in this regard let me explain why I often post answers without references: My opinion, at this stage of beta, is that *any* answer (including an incorrect one) is better than *no* answer.

The reason **even incorrect answers have been helpful** is that they prompt those who know better to at least chime in with a quick, "That's not right," and a downvote.  And often they decide, "Well I don't have time to produce what I consider to be a good answer, but I can certainly rattle one off that's better than *that*!"

In the worst case the incorrect answer is left standing.  That's a risk on every Stack Exchange site, and is specifically addressed here: [How do I know what the correct answer is?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/84/10)

In practice my impression is that (for this site at least) bad answers often stimulate better answers.

*I* don't ever intend to post a *bad* answer, but I often don't have time to post a properly documented answer.  I aspire to improve them when I have more time, but in order to maximize user engagement I've decided that a poorly-documented answer *now* is better than an excellent answer *later* (or, with my current schedule, perhaps *never*).

Ideally every answer would be worthy of printing in Law Review, and I agree we should aim for that level.  (I have [an enduring dream that we'll manage to attract a lot of law students to this site](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/79/10) who can and will raise the caliber of answers towards that ideal.)  However we should not let *perfect* be the enemy of *good* ... or even *barely adequate* if that's all the community can provide at the moment.

---

**Addendum:** There is a particularly broad exception to this discussion that I would *love* to see again: answers provided by experienced lawyers.  Unfortunately, to date I have only seen one user who made a career in the practice of law and who has made significant contributions to this site.  (He never touted that fact, so I'm not going to "out" him.)  Many of his answers are to questions about how the law works in real life, so they were more experiential and logical than referential.  But when he gave a crisp answer that could have been annotated, but wasn't, I gave a tremendous amount of credit to his experience.  [As we know, if practicing lawyers do post on this site they might take some pains to hide their identity](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/a/77/10).  It would be great if they put something like, "Reference: 25 years of legal practice," but perhaps we'll cross that bridge when we get there....

Answer (score 4):

If you're "answering based on common sense" that means that you're guessing.

Writing a guess as an answer is a really bad thing because guesses are by their nature unreliable.  When I'm doing research, It's always a pain to find questions flooded with unreliable answers.  It dilutes the usefulness of the Q&A site.

If you detect an answer that's looks like it's a guess then you should **downvote relentlessly**, because an unreliable answer is a useless answer.

---

On the flip side, the existence of references does not imply quality.  If an answer gives references, and those references look like they're from blog writers who are guessing, then you should still **downvote relentlessly**.  It's not the references or lack that is the important part.  It is the reliability.  References are merely a tool that can provide reliability.

Answer (score 4):

References are good for several reasons:

- They allow readers to not simply trust the answerer.
- They let readers start to learn how to do their own research in the future, by learning about the types of references that experts look to.
- They let people that disagree with the answer know exactly the chain of statute/reasoning/precedent that the answer is leaning on. This starts any disagreement on common ground. For example, perhaps the answer depends on an over-reading of a particular case's holding. If the answer doesn't reference the case, other experts can't really start a fruitful conversation about the discrepancy.

Of course, the type of reference will differ depending on the type of question. For example, "Is X infringement in Canada" will have different types of references than "What did Justice Alito mean when he said *superlegislative* in the Obergefell dissent."