# Law.SE Review – for Exemplary Answers

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

I've [peddled this query on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279816/241697) to no avail, but wondering if maybe this site wants to give it some consideration:

On occasion I read an exemplary answer. An answer so illuminating and/or well-researched that I want to revisit it to read again and again. An answer so good it makes me want to undo my other up-votes because, by comparison, a "useful" answer is just "acceptable."  An answer that would make it into *Law Review* were I an editor.  An answer that I would like to put on a pedestal as [an example for all others](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/q/199/10).

The best thing that I can do is to upvote it and award it a bounty.  But bounties are used more often to attract answers than to reward exemplary answers, so even if one were to search for [answers with bounties](http://data.stackexchange.com/law/query/edit/592519) one would not be able to find the *Best of Law.SE*.

(Votes and views are much worse heuristics, since those are just indicators of questions that have gone "hot" on the SE network.)

I'm going to (belatedly) start building a list on [my profile](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/10/feetwet?tab=profile), but not many people are going to look at that; I'm just one person; and I'll admit that there are some answers on the main site that I just haven't read.

Any thoughts on this question, or ideas on a broader mechanism for highlighting exemplary answers?

Comment: Why not start a _Law Stack Exchange Law Review_ that's curated and typeset and everything?  There's precedent for this kind of thing on SE; [Mi Yodeya Publications](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1568/mi-yodeya-publications) have turned out great.

Comment: The approach probably depends on whether we'd like to focus on curating a "best of" list, possibly as a link found on the side of the main page, or whether we want to reward exceptional answers without creating a hits list.  In either case, there's a subset of users determining what "exceptional" looks like.  Perhaps that makes sense on a site where specialists and laypeople interact, although it would force the SE model to adapt.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a stellar idea, but in the vein of *something is better than nothing* here's one possible answer:

A Community Wiki *Law.SE Review* post on Meta.  In this case, each answer to the post would list one Exemplary Answer, and voting could help curious users find the absolute best reads on the main site.

(Of course in the limit that *could* go terribly, but for now at least Meta.Law doesn't seem to be a madhouse.)

Comment: I feel that if we introduce something like that onto Meta... 1) It wouldn't be visible. 2) It will distract from the purpose of what meta really is. Perhaps, we could have a meta post that submits nominations, and than have a medium blog or something that acts as the journal?